# Are there any books on Lucene.NET

Tags: c#, lucene.net

I have searched on amazon and could not find a book on lucene.net. Have you guys came across a decent book on lucene.net?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may want to look at: [Lucene In Action](http://www.manning.com/hatcher2/).

Since Lucene.NET is a .NET port of the project, you may find it covers the necessary concepts, even though it's for Java. There should be a 2nd edition of it coming out soon.

The book covers:

- How to integrate Lucene into your applications
- Ready-to-use framework for rich document handling
- Case studies including Nutch, TheServerSide, jGuru, etc.
- Lucene ports to Perl, Python, C#/.Net, and C++
- Sorting, filtering, term vectors, multiple, and remote index searching
- The new SpanQuery family, extending query parser, hit collecting
- Performance testing and tuning
- Lucene add-ons (hit highlighting, synonym lookup, and others)
- Foreworded by Doug Cutting, the inventor of Lucene

Comment: Just a note the 2nd edition of "Lucene in Action" covers the latest version of Lucene.NET, which is 3.0.3.

Answer (score 0):

There's '[Lucene in Action](http://www.manning.com/hatcher2/)' for Java. It's quite similar.

Comment: I would wait for the second edition coming out soon...
http://www.amazon.co.uk/Lucene-Action-Erik-Hatcher/dp/1933988177/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1265845717&sr=8-2