# MVC Book That Covers Internal Search

Tags: asp.net-mvc, search

Is There Exists Any MVC Book Teaching How To Create Internal Search Engine Inside ASP.NET MVC Website? I've Searched a lot of Websites But Did not Find any Useful Articles.
In Fact I'm Looking For a Kind of Search Engine Tutorial That Gets The Request From Text Box And Display The Results in a New Page.

Like Tea Commerce Starter Kit

Comment: I imagine the search functionality itself has nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC.  Posting the search string and displaying the results would work like any other controller action.  The *actual search* is an entirely different story and takes place in your business logic.  We don't know what you're searching or how you plan to match strings against it, so there isn't much we can do to help.

Comment: In fact there is no link with ASP.Net MVC, what you need to find is the principle. You may also be interested by custom Google/Bing Search engines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the Lucene.NET project http://lucenenet.apache.org - it's mature and quite well-regarded.

> Lucene.Net is a port of the Lucene search engine library, written in C# and targeted at .NET runtime users.

Because it's a port, books on the original Java version will be useful - see this question: [Are there any books on Lucene.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241199/)